# Emacs Evil <E> mode and org-mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode, evil-mode

I have recent started using emacs, Evil and org-mode together. When taking notes in org-mode sometimes the program will go into an `< E >` mode which I can see on the status bar at the bottom of the frame. When starting emacs I usually see a `< N >` on the status bar.

I am assuming that

`< N >` - is for normal mode

`< I >` - is for insert mode

What is `< E >` mode?

How do I return to normal mode without having to restart emacs?

Comment: `(evil-define-state emacs "Emacs state." :tag " <E> " :message "-- EMACS --" :input-method t :intercept-esc nil)`  [Excerpt from `evil-states.el`]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It means you somehow got into "Emacs" state, which uses the standard Emacs keymap.  You can get back to "Normal state" with `M-x evil-normal-state`.  (Just in case you're brand new: `M-x` means "Meta-x", which in practice means "Alt-x").

Comment: M-x emacs-normal-state gives me a [ No match ] . Am I missing a package?

Comment: My bad; typo.  It's `evil-normal-state`.  I'll fix the answer.

Comment: Evil also maps C-z to return to evil normal state.